# Simple way to concatenate files with maximum size of source files

Tags: python, shell, concatenation, filesize, text-processing

I have a bunch of several million small text files. I would like to concatenate them to bigger files of around 10 MByte each in order to process them faster. Before I start with a Python script I wonder if there is a way to do so via shell - like a maximum file size parameter in cat or something similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe try `cat` on multiple files and push the standard output to a file? Like this:

`cat * > one_big_file`

If you don't want to process all files to one big file, but several smaller ones - maybe group their file names by some regex? (the exact solution then depends on how your filenames look like)

```
cat `grep [regex]` > one_big_file
```

You can also try creating one big file and then splitting it into several parts with:

```
split -b10m one_big_file part
```